# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. duplicate entry

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on Android Studio 1.5 and my gradle is the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.beatzplayer"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jl1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/JLayer1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mp3spi1.9.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/tritonus_share.jar')
}
```

I've sync, cleaned and rebuilt the Gradle but when I tried to run the app after choosing the device the app gave me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javazoom/jl/converter/Converter$PrintWriterProgressListener.class
```

After that, I read [Error after adding play-services library : ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164107/error-after-adding-play-services-library-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingf) so I add the following code:

```
compile('libs/JLayer1.0.1.jar') {
    exclude module: 'converter'
}
```

When I sync again the gradle it reported me this one:

```
Error:(29, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'
```

Comment: This error will come when two Libraries have same Files, so they will generate this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer androgo. I understand that but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: The simplest way to find out clash between two libraries is to remove them one by one and buil gradle.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. Removing the Jlayer library the error disappears. But I need that library, What can I do?

Comment: which two libraries have clashes?

Answer (score 0):

I thing as error say you have one jar file with different name having same classes

```
 compile files('libs/jl1.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/JLayer1.0.1.jar')
```

Both are same if one is not need delete that than build gradel
 once again