# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

This is the following error I got while executing the project.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/DebugUtils.class
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidStudio Menu, try to **Build/Clean** your Project then update old dependencies.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164107/error-after-adding-play-services-library-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingf) might also help. You need to update to the latest  because the latest plugin may cause issues with older Android Studio versions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. In terminal, execute the command in root project folder:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Hoping it will work.