# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/cast/RemoteMediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

After adding google play service

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0')
```

I am getting below error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/cast/RemoteMediaPlayer$6.class
```

Based on [Error after adding play-services library : ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164107/error-after-adding-play-services-library-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingf) I have added following line to gradle

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms.cast'
    }
```

Because of I do not need **Cast** I have removed **com.google.android.gms.cast** package

I do not know if above is right way to remove package, but still i am getting above error,

if any one resolve my issue

Thanks

Comment: It means that you are adding com/google/android/gms/cast/RemoteMediaPlayer twice. Are you using some jars?

Comment: Yes I have included aviary sdk it has so many jars and some other jars also i have added, right now i don't need google play service with cast package but don't know how to resolve